# Different results with Postman and RestSharp

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

I am testing a WebService on Postman v7.36.0 and I am getting the json without issue. So I copy the code that Postman gaves to use on C# but I am getting a different result a error response saying that I am not using a right input to obtain data (custom error from the source of the webservice).

¿Why I am getting diferent result if I just copied and pasted the code?
¿How can I debug  this?
¿Could be a problem the space between the date and the hour?
¿How can I be sure if the inputs that I am sending on Postman are really the same on the RestSharp code?

The code used needs a token that I am getting without problem on another webservive that I have to invoke previously. I copied and pasted the code given on Postman as well and it worked.

To get the token:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://URL:port/api");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("user", "user");
request.AddParameter("pass", "pass");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

To get the list of people:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://URL:PORT/api/API");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + thetoken);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("startDate", "2020-10-01 00:00");
request.AddParameter("finishDate", "2020-10-31 23:59");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

EDIT: The webservice returns a json with a list of person with the cuantity of days worked between start and finish date.

EDIT 2: I think the issue is about the date format or the way the dates are sent. Using Fiddler I see with Postaman the raw request is:

```
GET http://URL:port/api/API HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer thetokenxxxx
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b877f51b-550e-45ff-b4e4-50ca01412491
Host: URL:port
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 66

startDate=2020-10-01%2000%3A00&finishDate=2020-10-31%2023%3A59
```

But with RestSharp v105.2.3 the raw request is:

```
GET http://URL:port/api/API?startDate=2020-10-01%2000%3A00&finishDate=2020-10-31%2023%3A59 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer thetokenxxxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.1.0.0
Host: URL:port
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Comment: use fiddler to capture both requests and compare which might provide some idea what to  do next?

Comment: Could you show us pls your webservice code?

Comment: @Sergey I just use the webservice to get some information. I don't have the code.

Comment: But you have a URL of the webservice at least, yes?

Comment: Yes but you can't see te webservice definition. You gets <Error><Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message></Error> I would have to give you the user and the pass...

Comment: Providing additional information about the working Postman request may be helpful, as it is difficult to know how/why a webservice is rejecting a request without knowing what the service is expecting. Does the service require HTTPS (as an authorized service should)? Is it "startDate" and not "starDate"? Is it a GET request or should it be a POST request, given that you are setting the content type and this is how Postman translates parameters to RestSharp? Is your token variable in the C# being set?

Comment: @AdamG I think HTTPS is not set, on postman just works HTTP. Should be startDate. I get the token with POST then using the token with GET in another webservice should return the json with a list of people.

Comment: Please add both the responses

Comment: @coder_b Using Fiddler I see with Postaman the variables are sent on the body and with RestSharp not? Am I wrong? How can I add it to the body on RestSharp?

Comment: based on resharp doc, requestbody does not work on GET/HEAD, try using url segment,  and check your results, as mentioned @adam-g there is typo in startdate that could be main culprit.https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#get-or-post?

Comment: @coder_b I tried with request.AddUrlSegment("startDate", "2020-10-01%2000%3A00"); and also with request.AddUrlSegment("startDate", "2020-10-01 00:00"); and I got the same result (starDate was a typo just here) I have RestSharp v105.2.3 I can't use the latest version because of the dependecies.